# Method not found: 'guard'. return internals.guard(

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

i am new to flutter.when i run this code on flutter web this error occurs.
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-1.0.7/lib/src/internals.dart:10:20:

some one help to get rid of the problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you updated your flutter sdk to Beta channel, Downgrade your flutter sdk to Stable Channel. Current stable version is 2.10.3

> Flutter downgrade command

```
flutter downgrade v2.10.3
```

and than

```
Downgrade flutter to version 2.10.3
? [y|n]:
Type y for Yes to confirm changes
```

> If the above method does'nt work try this

```
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13 
cloud_firestore_web: ^2.6.13
```

add the above the packages to your pubspec.yaml file with updated version

Answer (score 1):

```
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13 
cloud_firestore_web: ^2.6.13
```

add the above the packages to your pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 1):

Either you can upgrade your all firebase packages to the available latest version (Mainly `firebase_core` to the latest version) or else you can modify the error which we get for `internals` like below:

**Step-1:** Open the `internals.dart` file of the firebase package which you face the error.

**Step-2:** Change function use from `internals.guard()` to `internals.guardWebExceptions()` like below:

From:

```
return internals.guard(
    cb,
    plugin: 'app-check',
    codeParser: (code) => code.replaceFirst('appCheck/', ''),
  );
```

To:

```
return internals.guardWebExceptions(
    cb,
    plugin: 'app-check',
    codeParser: (code) => code.replaceFirst('appCheck/', ''),
  );
```

> **Notes:**
>
> - This modification will remain locally so remember to change every time if you do `flutter clean` or run the app in a different system.
> - Above example is for Firebase AppCheck. You can get the same error for another firebase service. So, modify only that `internals` from the specific firebase service error that you have faced.

Comment: "upgrade your all firebase packages to the available latest version"
Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below thing worked for me :

I upgraded :

firebase_core: ^1.0.4  to   firebase_core: ^1.13.1

cloud_firestore: ^1.0.6 to   cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10

firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0 -> firebase_analytics: ^9.1.2

Then do:

flutter clean

flutter run

Refer : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8194
For more info

Comment: This i s my Answer, Remove the answer  or else I'll raise flag

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan, NP i will remove it. But could you look at difference, In my case i also required to upgrade firebase core and firebase_analytics